# Can I use the return type "object" in Java? Dangers?

Tags: java, return-type

During a project the need for a queue supporting two different datatypes arose. I solved this by creating a java.util linked list using java.util queue interface. I do however need to use the return type Object

```
public Object dequeue(){
    return queue.poll();
}
```

Returning "Object" feels weird and feels like it could cause a lot of errors.
My question is really, is this okay? Is there a better solution to solve my problem?

I'm including the full code below.

```
private static class DualQueue<T, U>{

    private final Queue<Object> queue;

    public DualQueue(){
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void enqueueT(T item) {
        queue.add(item);
    }

    public void enqueueU(U item) {
        queue.add(item);
    }

    public Object dequeue() {
        return queue.poll();
    }

    public Object peek() {
        return queue.peek();
    }

    public boolean queueIsEmpty() {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you *can* use `Object`, that's how all collections worked before generics were added to Java. Yes, it *does* get annoying and is a potential source for problems. If you can't change your design to be able to give a specific type for each method return value, then this might be the best you can do.

Comment: you can, but you lose static type analysis which is one of keystones of java programming

Comment: Which are the 2 different datatypes? To those have a common superclass other than `Object`? Can you make them implement the same interface maybe? Otherwise you might be stuck with `Queue<T extends Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a method to return `Object` in and of itself is not "dangerous". However, if the caller casts the returned `Object` to a type which it isn't, an exception would be thrown, and that can be considered dangerous.

If you want to prevent the caller from doing that, you can design the API so that it is safer for the caller by implementing different methods that deals with `T` and `U` specifically.

```
class DualQueue<T, U>{

    private final Class<T> tClass;
    private final Class<U> uClass;

    private final Queue<Object> queue;

    public DualQueue(Class<T> tClass, Class<U> uClass){
        this.tClass = tClass;
        this.uClass = uClass;
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void enqueueT(T item) {
        queue.add(item);
    }

    public void enqueueU(U item) {
        queue.add(item);
    }

    public T dequeueT() {
        if (peekT() != null) {
            return tClass.cast(queue.poll());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public U dequeueU() {
        if (peekU() != null) {
            return uClass.cast(queue.poll());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public T peekT() {
        var t =  queue.peek();
        if (tClass.isInstance(t)) {
            return tClass.cast(t);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public U peekU() {
        var u =  queue.peek();
        if (uClass.isInstance(u)) {
            return uClass.cast(u);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean queueIsEmpty() {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

`dequeueT`, `dequeueU`, `peekT`, `peekU` will all return null if the next item in the queue isn't that type.

Answer (score 0):

Are the types you want to add to the queue defined by you? In that case you could create an interface and have the two classes implement it. That way you can add them to the queue. It can also be a generic interface kind-of-a-wrapper, e.g.:

```
    interface QueueAddable {
        <T extends QueueAddable> T get(Class<T> type);
    }
```

This is something I may do - honestly I don't know it that is a good solution, but it's definitely a way to put different types in your queue with typesafe casts to get them out. A little example of what I mean.

```
public class MyClass {

    interface QueueAddable {
        <T extends QueueAddable> T get(Class<T> type);
    }

    public static class MyOtherClass implements QueueAddable {
        public <T extends QueueAddable> T get(Class<T> type) {
            return type.cast(this);
        }
    }

    public static class MyThirdClass implements QueueAddable {
        public <T extends QueueAddable> T get(Class<T> type) {
            return type.cast(this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Queue<QueueAddable> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(new MyOtherClass());
        queue.add(new MyThirdClass());

        QueueAddable a = queue.poll();
        if (a instanceof MyOtherClass) {
            MyOtherClass object = a.get(MyOtherClass.class);
        }

        if (a instanceof MyThirdClass) {
            MyThirdClass object = a.get(MyThirdClass.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, the task you're looking to do isn't necessarily possible in a statically-typed language, like Java.

You're essentially telling the compiler to infer the data type, which is not its abstraction.

So, there are a few work arounds.  Many will say to simply use the `Object` class, although this is not recommended by the Java implementors, for several reasons.

My first recommendation is, if you're storing `String` values and numbers, then just store the numbers as `String` values also.

Another approach would be to create an empty `interface`.

```
interface Example { }
```

And, then create an implementation for each type of value.

```
class ValueA implements Example {
    String string;

    ValueA(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}

class ValueB implements Example {
    int integer;

    ValueB(int integer) {
        this.integer = integer;
    }
}
```

And, then use the following `DualQueue` implementation.

```
private static class DualQueue {

    private final Queue<Example> queue;

    public DualQueue() {
        queue = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void enqueueT(ValueA item) {
        queue.add(item);
    }

    public void enqueueU(ValueB item) {
        queue.add(item);
    }

    public Example dequeue() {
        return queue.poll();
    }

    public Example peek() {
        return queue.peek();
    }

    public boolean queueIsEmpty() {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }
}
```